# get last Conversation

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need your help!

Problem: I have a message system between users and I need to get the last conversation of all conversations. This means, I have to get the last written message and the conversation with probably sooner message between user1 and user2.

My 'message' table structure is this:

```
'id' | 'uidfrom' | 'uidto' | 'content' | 'cdate'
```

[image]

'uidfrom' is the user who wrote the message and 'uidto' is the user who received the message.

Do you guys have an idea or is it even possible, to catch the last conversation? So in this case the last written message is 'id' = 5 and now I need to get the whole conversation between 'uidfrom' = 1 AND 'uidto' = 2 + 'uidfrom' = 2 AND 'uidto' = 1.

EDIT: The query should be dynamic. So it should return the latest message plus the conversation. E.g. when message with `id = 3` is written at `2016-07-19- 17:13:50`, it should only return this message, because there is just one in this type of conversation. Any more ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from message
where
  uidfrom IN (select uidfrom,uidto from message order by id desc limit 0,1) AND
  uidto IN (select uidfrom,uidto from message order by id desc limit 0,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was trying your query, but first of all I got the error `This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery` and when I remove the Limit I got `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. So to fix this I ended up with this query `SELECT *
      FROM message
      WHERE
      uidfrom IN (SELECT uidfrom FROM message ORDER BY id DESC) AND
      uidto IN (SELECT uidfrom FROM message ORDER BY id DESC)`. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to find out which message was last written and then select the uidfrom + uidto to catch up the conversation? For now I always get the same conversation, but if `message with id 3` later written then `message with id 5`, I still get the conversation between `user 1` and `user 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try
Select *
from message
where
  uidfrom IN (select uidfrom,uidto from message where id = (select max(id) from message)) AND
  uidto IN (select uidfrom,uidto from message where id = (select max(id) from message))

Comment: `Select * from message where uidfrom IN (select uidfrom from message where id = (select max(id) from message)) AND uidto IN (select uidto from message where id = (select max(id) from message))` will give me only message with `id = 1` and `id = 5`. So `Id = 2` and `Id = 4` won't be in the results.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you which will give you row 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Select * from stack1 where uidfrom IN (select uidfrom from stack1 where id = (select max(id) from stack1) UNION select uidto from stack1 where id = (select max(id) from stack1)) AND uidto IN (select uidfrom from stack1 where id = (select max(id) from stack1) UNION select uidto from stack1 where id = (select max(id) from stack1))

Comment: Yes it works, like the other queries, but the point is that I need to dynamically get the last conversation. So I guess these things need to be in the query: something to get the last written message and something to get the whole conversation based on the last written message